# toplevel abstraction in line 1

Tags: oz, mozart

I see the following error when running the program at the bottom:-

```
%***************************** failure **************************
%**
%** Tell: 1024 = two_10
%**
%** Call Stack:
%** toplevel abstraction in line 1, column 0, PC = 125792828
%**--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Mozart-oz program:-

```
declare
two_10 = 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2

{Browse two_10*two_10}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I get a different error message. Nevertheless, a variable name begins with a capital letter, for example, "Two_10". I suppose you want "two_10" to be a variable.

Comment: @beroal it worked. Please make that an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oz, variables must be capitalised. Using `Two_10 = 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2` solves the problem.

You could also use `{Number.pow 2 10}` to compute 2 to the 10th power.